# WordPress: is there a wordpress alternative to mysql_num_rows?

Tags: wordpress

Does WordPress $wpdb have an alternative for mysql_num_rows?

I'm trying to count the number of rows as you can see :)

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I used the php count() function which works great :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a quite easy way for counting rows:

```
global $wpdb;

$allrows = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_wordpresstable");

echo $allrows;
```

Also visit:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description